# Something that combines Oauth, OpenID, FB Connect, etc?

Tags: javascript, openid, oauth, fbconnect

So there are these different open authentication schemes, such as OAuth, OpenID, and Facebook Connect among others. Are there any packages that provide a common interface for these various systems? It seems that it would be a boon to someone with a site to have a single interface layer for interoperating with these disparate sign-in systems.

Comment: To which language are you interested?

Comment: I apologize for not specifying that. I am mainly talking about javascript, since most of these protocols are most often used directly from the browser.

Comment: There is code to log in a user using OpenID in PHP too, for example; that is the reason I asked.

Comment: Those protocols have parts that require interaction with browsers, but most of their work is done server-side. So using pure javascript implementation probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Not in Javascript - by design any browser client scripting runs in a bit of a walled garden and authentication should be separated from it (for instance by using HTTP-only authentication cookies). You're always going to have a significant server side component to any authentication model.

Answer (score 0):

It is a boon to someone.

Janrain is in the single sign on business and provides some sort of middleware coupled to their servers.  I think you have to sign up for an account to use it, and usage is metered.

I understand there is a "free" level of their service. I haven't used it, maybe someone who has can comment further.

http://www.janrain.com/